# Can app.config be modified for spawned processes?

Tags: .net, process, app-config

Here's what I want to do: build a .net console application with an app.config file. Then, from a second application, spawn instances of the console application, which each instance having some attributes of it's app.config settings tweaked.

So far I've figured that this can be done if the binary is copied and renamed each time I spawn the process, since each binary looks for an app.config file with a matching name. But I'd prefer to do this with a single exe and config file.

Answer (score 0):

Using Commandline Parameters to choose the config values in the same app.config...
You can spawn processes from .Net with extra parameters using ProcessInfo

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This scheme is basically using the command line for configuration rather than app.config. But a reasonable approach. My specific interest is modifying the behavior of the MembershipProvider, so it won't work in this case.